# generating high-resolution dendrogram plot in R

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram

I am trying to generate a high-resolution dendrogram in R.

The difficulty is that there are more than 200 leaf nodes, and each node is identified by a string. I would like to ensure that each of these string labels is readable in the generated (printed) plot.

Another thing is that I would like to switch the original x-axis (corresponding to leaf nodes) to the y-axis, and switch the original y-axis to x-axis. For more clear demonstration purposes, I would like to add one more x-axis (which corresponds to the distance information in the switched plot) on the top of the plot.  How can one do this in R?

Comment: Could you provide more information with what functions you intend to make these plots. There are multiple systems in R (ggplot, lattice, base). Furthermore, if you could provide us with an example dataset, that would help very much.

Comment: For 200 strings, side by side, to be readable, you going to need to print it on some pretty big paper.

Comment: Hi, paul, the input will be a 210*210 matrix of dissimilarity matrix based on correlation coefficient.I am new to R, so I do not have much idea about which exact library should I use for generating this kind of plot. I notice that there have more than one libs that can do that. But I do not know which one is able to support high-resolution ploting and allow me to switch the placement of axis and add more axiss if I want.

Comment: Just more clarifications, I will generate this plot for poster.

Comment: The `ggdendro` package allows you to convert dendrogram plotting data to data.frames which you can then plot using `ggplot`.  This might help you solve most of these problems (except the dual axis). http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdendro/index.html

Comment: In addition to Andrie, using ggsave from the ggplot2 package, you can quite easily save a high resolution png or pdf file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with standard R functions.

## Plot a dendrogram

To plot a dendrogram from a distance matrix you can use the `hclust` function. See its man page for further details on the algorithms available.

```
# To produce a dummy distance matrix
distMatrix <- dist(matrix(1:9, ncol=3))

# To convert it into a tree
tree <- hclust(distMatrix)
```

For the plot, the `dendrogram` class provides a useful `plot` method. Just convert the hclust output to dendrogram and plot it :

```
dendro <- as.dendrogram(tree)
```

This method provides a `horiz` argument that can switch X and Y axis, test the following :

```
plot(dendro, horiz=TRUE)
plot(dendro, horiz=FALSE)
```

## Manage its size

For the readability, it is up to the device you use for exporting the image. R can produce huge images, it is up to the user to set the size and resolution. See the man page for `png` or `pdf` for further details (width, height and res are interesting arguments).

An other track to follow is the graphical parameters : playing with the various `cex` values, you will be able to resize the labels. See the man page of `par` for further details.

Readability is quite human oriented, so i don't think you will find an automated way to obtain a readable plot automaticaly, but with a few manual tunning you can achieve it with the tools i mentionned. If automation is mandatory, it can be obtained using some `par` elements generated by R like `cin` to predict the needed device width, but it is much simpler to tune it manually.

## New axis

The `axis` function can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to get this:

```
# get font factor
pdf(); ff<-72/par()$ps; dev.off();
# if there are more than 20 entries 
if (dim(x)[2] > 20) {
    # scale output by font size
    pdf(fout, height=dim(x)[2]/ff)
} else {
    pdf(fout)
}
# increase right margin width
op <- par(mar = par("mar") + c(0,0,0,2*max(nchar(colnames(x)))/ff))
# plot horizontally
plot(as.dendrogram(hclust(distance), hang=-1), main="Dissimilarity = 1 - Correlation", xlab="", horiz=T)
# restore margin
par(op)
dev.off();
```